# Where to find file BHYVE_UEFI.fd

Tags: osx, freebsd, virtual-machine, uefi

I have the FreeBSD port of Bhyve hypervisor, xhyve on my MacBook and I can run the tinylinux with it.
To run Windows the instructions and the provided shell script state that I need the UEFI image in the subject of my post.
I don't know how to obtain this file, it doesn't appear to be included with the xhyve package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is in the firmware package

```
# pkg install bhyve-firmware
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the only place where I found this file available [https://people.freebsd.org/~grehan/bhyve_uefi/](https://people.freebsd.org/%7Egrehan/bhyve_uefi/)

Answer (score -1):

http://pkg.freebsd.org/freebsd:12:x86:64/latest/All/ search for uefi-edk2-bhyve- package, It's on it